# Renaming columns in pandas dataframe during groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas, rename, calculated-columns

I tried to rename the column that has been obtained as the result of groupby & count operation like below:

```
dfa = df.groupby('Product_ID').Product_ID.count().rename(columns={0: "Product",1:"Sale_count"}).reset_index()
print(dfa[:1])
```

the output obtained is

```
 Product_ID     0
0  P00000142  1130
```

The column names are not what I specified. So I changed it again using the below command

```
dfa.columns =['product','sales']
print(dfa[:1])

 product  sales
0  P00000142   1130
```

Then I got the expected column names. However I believe it shall be obtained during the first method dataframe.rename itself. What is wrong in the 1st code snippet `dfa = df.groupby('Product_ID').Product_ID.count().rename(columns={0: "Product",1:"Sale_count"}).reset_index()`that I did not get the expected output.

Comment: do you need `df.groupby('Product_ID').size().reset_index(name='sales_count')` ?

Comment: `df.groupby('Product_ID').Product_ID.count()` will result in a series, not a dataframe.  Your output, however, _is_ a dataframe.  It seems that your code is not quite correct, or else the output looks to be inconsistent.

Comment: @anky_91: that worked ! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you need:

```
df.groupby('Product_ID').size().reset_index(name='sales_count')
```